# Replace end of line with datestamp

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to prep a file for Database import using a powershell script.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=38619771487389595658

I'm trying to remove the first line and add a date stamp to the end of the line. This is what I have been trying:

```
$date = get-date -format "dd-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS"
(Get-Content example.csv) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`r`n", $date
} | Select -skip 1 | Set-Content result.csv
```

Ideally, I'd like to append the date and a comma, but I've even tried "TEST" as the value to replace and it still doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot ... just use the `+` operator to append to the end of each line. This example appends a comma and the date.

```
$date = Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS';
Get-Content example.csv | % { $_ + ',' + $date } | Select -skip 1 | Set-Content result.csv;
```